# Filter/search - Remove the option to see searchable item before searching

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to HTML,CSS and JS. Only doing a site for work that is only being showed locally on our network.

I developed a quick site and want to add a search option to search links on my index page.

I found a code online that works very good, but considering that I have 75+ links to add to the search. I want to remove the window where you see what to search for. But I want the window to appear once typed the first letter of your search word.

found the code here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" 
 placeholder="Search for names..">

 <ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
 </ul>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
 var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
 input = document.getElementById('myInput');
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

   // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the 
   search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
     a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
     if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
       li[i].style.display = "none";
  }       
     } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display: none to the links in your css so if anything matches it will be displayed, also in the JS if it matches it will be display="block" instead of display="".
e.g:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li a');
var searchbar = document.querySelector('#myInput');

//Append the eventlistener
searchbar.addEventListener('keyup', searchfunction, false);

function searchfunction(_) {  
  //Value of the searchbar
  var query = _.target.value.toLowerCase(); 

  //Check if the title matches the current value of the searchbar
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    //toLowerCase to make it case insensitive (optional)
    var title = item.innerText.toLowerCase();
    
    //if the search query matches at any point display it
    if (title.indexOf(query) > -1) {
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    //If the search query is empty do not display any links
    if (query == '') {
     item.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
    
  });
}
```

```css
#myUL li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" 
 placeholder="Search for names..">

 <ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The least modification to your code would be to just call `myFunction()` initially (`(2)` in the snippet). To make it work, you have to alter the filter condition a bit -- only show items if a filter is available (i.e. `filter` is truthy, `(1)` in the snippet).

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    /* (1): add filter() */
    if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }       
  } 
}
/* (2): call myFunction() initially */
myFunction()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" 
 placeholder="Search for names..">

 <ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I also slightly altered the `<input onkeyup="myFunction()"/>` to `<input oninput="myFunction()"/>` because that's a bit more robust. But you could very well stay with `onkeyup`.